# tinymce mouse paste not working

Tags: wordpress, tinymce

i want to enable mouse paste in tinymce. when i click paste it displays error saying "cut/paste/copy is disabled in Firefox". i searched this on their forums (http://www.tinymce.com/forum/viewtopic.php?id=20637) and they say its browser(my Firefox) issue and they cannot fix it, then how come it's not an issue for WordPress? how they fixed this issue. are they using another j/s
to handle it?

I really need a solution please help example would be great

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i found a simpler solution thought it will help another, thank you "Thariama" letting me know there is "contextmenu plugin" i didn't even knew what it is, that was the problem maker i just removed it and that solved my problem i think that's what WordPress people done. just do this...

remove the *contextmenu plugin* in your tinymce init:

plugins : "autolink,lists,pagebreak,fullscreen,*contextmenu*",

Answer (score 1):

Using the contextmenu plugin (or an own plugin based on that one) you can create your own rightclick menu and insert the options and functions you like there.

Comment: The issue for me was the "paste" plugin.